# Who is this? Is it Nrihingha Dev?

Tags: identification-request

The Pic is taken in The Shiva temple of Tiruvannamalai in Tamil Nadu. I wonder if it is Nrisingha Dev (Vishnu avatar) or a protector?

[image: Picture from Tiruvannamalai Shiva temple]

Comment: He's obviously a shaiva figure, given the forehead marking.

Comment: Definitely it's not Narasimha (Half man and half Lion) or sharabeshwara (part lion and part bird). Crazy minds creativity?

Comment: Are you sure you are not mistaken with name Nrihinga?

Answer (score 1):

Respected sir, it seems like ... sri sharabeshwara an avatar of shiva,  who tried to pacify (or rather fight?? ) with narasimha. Sharbeshwars wives are pratyangira and shoolini durga.

Answer (score 1):

Namaste,

This is neither Sri Nrisimha Svami or Sri Sharabheshwara Svami as both these forms have non-human heads. Sri Nrisimha Svami has the face of a lion and the body of a human while Sri Sharabheshwara Svami is essentially an epithet of the mystical "Sharabha" creature.

This icon has a human face with a body of some big cat (lion or tiger). It is none other than [Maharshi Vyaghrapada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyaghrapada) of ancient lore.

Comment: Welcome .I think Vyaghrapada's  feet only were like lions feet , but not the half body. He is also pictured as standing on two feet (same as lion's) like human beings. But here the idol is bit different than that portrait of him.

Comment: While what you say is true, that Maharshi Vyaghrapada's feet alone were that of a Vyaghra or tiger, popular depictions of the revered sage depict him in a very similar manner, especially around shrines of Lord Shiva in South India. Further, this is not an idol; i.e. one used for daily worship. This is more akin to a (for a lack of proper English word) prop used during festivals. The idols of the God and Goddesses are mounted atop this 'prop' and taken for procession. Also note the idol has only two feet.

Comment: It is worth noting that this this is used only for festivals where the idols of the Gods and Goddesses are taken out for procession. A standing idol would not quite be suited and hence the "back" has been elongated to accommodate  the idols for procession along with other paraphernalia like prabhavali etc.

Comment: Ok similarly Vyaghrapada is often portrayed with folded hands. Praying pose.:-)

Comment: Good identification @Arunagirinathar